# Sharing data between two subdomains on different applications in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, data-sharing

We need to share data between subdomains in web sites using different applications developed using ASP.Net and deployed on IIS. We have following ideas in mind :-

a. Sharing data using cookies : But this idea will allow only to share us simple strings and more over it will get failed if browser don't support cookies

b. Sharing data using session : But for that we will have to use out proc session handlining techniques

Can any one please let us know if there is some other good technique for this?

Thanks

Tarunjit Singh

Answer (score 0):

**To share data, use a database**, or use common files, and use that files to save there yous common data.

### Other possible solutions.

If you like to send data from one page to another, you can use post them.

You can also use the url, to send data on variables.

You can also use [memory mapped files.](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files)

And here is one more example how to [share memory across different apps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/242386/VB-NET-MEMORY-MAPPING-ACROSS-DIFFERENT-RUNNING-APP)